# ld.exe: cannot find -lvcruntime140 when compiling previously working Cython module on new 3.5 install

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, compiler-errors, cython

I'm afraid I don't really know what to provide here. I'm a bit lost. Google sends me in entirely irrelevant directions.

I've just upgraded to Python 3.5 and am now trying to get my current project working with it. Unfortunately, part of it is done in Cython, and I've had to spend the last three days trying to get Python to talk to MinGW. Now I've done that via [this patch](https://www.mail-archive.com/python-bugs-list@python.org/msg255165.html), but the compilation still fails.

This file compiled flawlessly previously, so presumably it's something about the way Cython is set up.

Here's the full text of the command I give and the error message:

```
>python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32

running build
running build_ext
building 'fx' extension
C:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python35-32\include -IC:\Python35-32\include -c fx.c -o build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\fx.o
In file included from C:\Python35-32\include/Python.h:65:0,
                 from fx.c:12:
C:\Python35-32\include/pytime.h:113:5: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list
     _PyTime_round_t round);
     ^
C:\Python35-32\include/pytime.h:118:5: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list
     _PyTime_round_t round);
     ^
In file included from C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1781:0,
                 from C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                 from C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from fx.c:250:
C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:12:9: note: #pragma message: C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
 #pragma message(_WARN___LOC__"Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
         ^
writing build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\fx.cp35-win32.def
C:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\fx.o build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\fx.cp35-win32.def -LC:\Python35-32\libs -LC:\Python35-32\PCbuild\win32 -lpython35 -lvcruntime140 -o build\lib.win32-3.5\fx.cp35-win32.pyd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lvcruntime140
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'C:\\mingw\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

I've tried adding `#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION` to the beginning of the generated `fx.c` and trying again, but that just produces different error messages along the lines of "that method does not exist" which suggests Cython depends on the deprecated API of which it speaks.

Here's setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(options={'build_ext': {'compiler': 'mingw32'},
      "compiler_directives":{"language_level": "3"}},
      ext_modules=cythonize("fx.pyx"),
      include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
```

And finally, here's fx.pyx itself:

```
import pygame
cimport numpy
import numpy.random
import random
from libc.stdlib cimport abs

#I added this because some soverflo answer suggested it but it doesn't appear to help
numpy.import_array() 

cpdef chromatic_aberration(surface,int intensity=5):
    cdef int x,y,z,maxx,maxy
    cdef numpy.ndarray[unsigned char,ndim=3] array
    cdef numpy.ndarray[unsigned char,ndim=2] r,g,b
    r=pygame.surfarray.pixels_red(surface)
    g=pygame.surfarray.pixels_green(surface)
    b=pygame.surfarray.pixels_blue(surface)
    array=pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(surface)

    maxx,maxy=surface.get_rect().bottomright

    for x in range(maxx):
        for y in range(maxy):
            try:
                pass
                array[x,y,0]=r[x+intensity,y]
                array[x,y,1]=g[x,y+intensity]
                array[x,y,2]=b[x+intensity,y-intensity]
            except IndexError:
                pass

cpdef mapped_chromatic_aberration(surface, numpy.ndarray[int,ndim=2] intensitymap):
    cdef int x,y,z,maxx,maxy,intensity
    cdef numpy.ndarray[unsigned char,ndim=3] array
    cdef numpy.ndarray[unsigned char,ndim=2] r,g,b
    r=pygame.surfarray.pixels_red(surface)
    g=pygame.surfarray.pixels_green(surface)
    b=pygame.surfarray.pixels_blue(surface)
    array=pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(surface)

    maxx,maxy=surface.get_rect().bottomright

    for x in range(maxx):
        for y in range(maxy):
            try:
                pass
                intensity=intensitymap[x,y]
                array[x,y,0]=r[x+intensity,y]
                array[x,y,1]=g[x,y+intensity]
                array[x,y,2]=b[x+intensity,y-intensity]
            except IndexError:
                pass

cpdef random_chromatic_aberration(surface,int intensity=5):
    mapped_chromatic_aberration(surface,numpy.random.random_integers(-intensity,intensity,surface.get_rect().bottomright))

cpdef chroma_warp(surface,int x, int y, int radius, int power):
    cdef numpy.ndarray[int,ndim=2] warpmap
    warpmap=numpy.zeros(surface.get_size(), dtype=numpy.int)
    cdef int maxdist = radius ** 2
    cdef int maxx, minx, maxy, miny, warpx, warpy

    for xofst in range(-radius, radius):
        for yofst in range(-radius, radius):
            warpx=x+xofst
            warpy=y+yofst
            warpmap[warpx,warpy] = ((abs(xofst) + abs(yofst)) * power) // 100

    mapped_chromatic_aberration(surface, warpmap)

def screenshake(surf,intensity=3):
    surf.scroll(random.randint(-intensity,intensity),random.randint(-intensity,intensity))
```

I've also tried using `build_ext` instead of `build`, but that produced identical results.

I'm sorry for the "here's some text what's wrong with my program" style question but I seriously have no idea what the hell is going on. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The warning about the deprecated numpy api is irrelevant and should be ignored (it comes up on every compiler and with every version of Python). I assume you've downloaded and installed the visual studio runtime (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=48145). Otherwise I don't know.

Comment: @DavidW I've actually done that *too*, but it didn't work. I've got it configured to use MinGW instead. Nothing works! Yaaaaaay!

Comment: My kind of impression is that MinGw and Python 3.5 don't yet mix (see "specific notes" on https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/217 for example). So you may be out of luck. I'm not 100% sure though - things may have improved since then.